# Convergence and absolute convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to prove that the following series converges, but not absolutely,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[ \exp \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n} \right) -1\right] $$

Since no other information is given, I have tried to prove it using the ratio and root tests. I can prove using the root test that the exp part converges, but the -1 part will always diverge.
Any ideas?

Comment: Taylor expand the exponential term. You'll find something familiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Taylor series we have

$$\exp \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n} \right) -1=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

- The series $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is convergent by Leibniz theorem
- The series $\sum \mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$ is convergent by comparison with a Riemann series

so the given series is convergent.

Moreover

$$\left|\exp \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n} \right) -1\right|\sim_\infty\frac1n$$
so the given series isn't absolutely convergent by comparison with the harmonic series.

Answer (score 2):

This is based on the asymptotics:
$$
\exp\left(\frac{(-1)^n}n\right) = 1 + \frac{(-1)^n}n + \frac 12\left(\frac{(-1)^n}n\right)^2
+ o\left(\left(\frac{(-1)^n}n\right)^2\right)
$$